# Mvc Remote Attribute is sending "undefined" in query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to remote validate some code and for the parameter, its passing `undefined` in as a parameters. Here is my validation code:

```
[OutputCache(Location = OutputCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public class ValidationController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult IsUserNameAvailable(string userName, int? UserId)
    {
        var users = new BusinessLayer.BdsAdmin.Users();
        if (UserId == null || UserId == 0)
            // Do something
        else // Do something else

        if (users.Count == 0)
        {
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        string msg = string.Format("{0} is already taken and is not available.", userName);
        return Json(msg, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Here is my model:

```
public class EditUserAdministrationViewModel
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter a user name.")]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    [Remote("IsUserNameAvailable", "Validation", AdditionalFields = "UserId")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    // More properties
}
```

Looking at the request in Fiddler, here is what I see:

```
GET /Validation/IsUserNameAvailable?UserName=sara&UserId=undefined
```

Why is MVC injecting the string `undefined` into the request instead of the actual UserId?

Comment: you need to have HiddenFor(m=>m.UserId) in the view

Comment: @DanHunex -- That was exactly correct. Thank you. Make it an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add

```
  @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.UserId)
```

at the view so that the binder will bind it to the remote validation controller or otherwise there is no value to bind